# i am trying to use e.KeyChar in c# but it wont work

Tags: c#

So I am trying to use `e.KeyChar to detect when some key is pressed.
When i change

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

to

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
```

so `e.KeyChar` is recognised as a argument.
it shows this error:

```
"No overload for 'timer1_Tick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'" in Form1.Designer.
```

Can you please help me with this problem?

Comment: No timer tick event takes a KeyPressEventArgs argument.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a method called `timer1_Tick` to respond to a key press event? Are you sure you're really hooking the events up correctly? (We don't have a lot of context here...)

Answer (score -2):

Create keypress event handler method. In that method you can use
e.keyChar() to get pressed key